# рекурсия в С# на примере из книги шилдта

Tags: c#

```csharp
class RevStr { 
    // Вывести символьную строку в обратном порядке
    public void DisplayRev(string str) {
        if (str.Length > 0)
            DisplayRev(str.Substring(1, str.Length-1));
        else
            return;
        Console.Write(str[0]);
    }
}

class RevStrDemo { 
    static void Main() { 
        string s = "Это тест"; , 
        RevStr rsOb = new RevStr (); 
        Console.WriteLine("Исходная строка: " + s); 
        Console.Write("Перевернутая строка: "); 
        rsOb.DisplayRev(s); 
        Console.WriteLine() ; 
    } 
}
```

Не могу понять, как тут строка выводится в обратном порядке? Как вообще работает тут рекурсия? Почему вот тут:

```
DisplayRev(str.Substring(1, str.Length-1));
```

граница начинается с 1?

Comment: а вы вообще что-нибудь о рекурсии знаете/понимаете? Возможно, вам имеет смысл просто прочитать что это, и как оно работает? Пример в общем-то элементарный

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Смотрите.

Давайте-ка рекурсивно определим, что такое «напечатать строку в обратном порядке». Это просто

1. отделить начальный символ (потому что он должен напечататься последним)
2. напечатать остаток строки в обратном порядке
3. напечатать отделённый начальный символ.

На примере строки `"ABCD"`:

1. начальный символ — `'A'`
2. печатаем остаток `"BCD"` в обратном порядке, будет напечатано `DCB`
3. печатаем `'A'`, в итоге напечатано `DCBA`.

`str.Substring(1, str.Length-1)` как раз и есть хвост строки, начиная от символа с индексом 1 (начальный символ строки имеет индекс 0), и длиной на 1 меньшей, чем длина строки.

---

Обратите внимание, что пример Шилдта плох во многих смыслах.

1. Использование рекурсии тут не оправдано, так как длинные строки (больше 1000 символов) не редкость, и это может привести к переполнению стека.
2. Задача имеет простое итеративное решение, использование рекурсии гораздо медленнее и затратнее по ресурсам.
3. В коде используется класс `RevStr`, который не имеет семантики «обратной строки». Это просто класс-хелпер, и он должен быть статическим, так как экземпляр его не несёт самостоятельного смысла. (И его имя не отражает ничего.)
4. Строка много раз копируется, что неэффективно. Проще передавать начальный индекс существующей строки для обработки.
5. Используется неподходящая перегрузка `string.Substring`, которая заставляет вычислять длину вручную. Есть более простая перегрузка (от данного индекса до конца строки).
6. Код ещё плох и тем, что у класса `RevStr` слишком много ответственностей: он и разворачивает строку, и выводит её. В результате теряется гибкость: мы не можем с этим классом перевернуть строку и использовать её дальше, без вывода.
7. Смешивание в одном методе модельной семантики (переворот строки) и семантики представления (вывод на консоль) — плохо.

---

Более хорошим кодом был бы такой (этот вариант учитывает пункты 3—7):

```
static class StringHelper
{
    public string Reverse(string s)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        ReverseImpl(sb, 0, s);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    private void ReverseImpl(StringBuilder sb, int startIdx, string s)
    {
        if (startIdx >= s.Length)
            return;
        ReverseImpl(sb, startIdx + 1, s);
        sb.Append(s[startIdx]);
    }
}

class StringReverseDemo
{
    static void Main()
    { 
        string s = "Это тест"; , 
        Console.WriteLine("Исходная строка: " + s); 
        Console.WriteLine("Перевернутая строка: " + StringHelper.Reverse(s)); 
    }
}
```

Вариант, в котором возможна хвостовая рекурсия, а значит, он частично решает проблему п. 2:

```
static class StringHelper
{
    public string Reverse(string s)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        ReverseImpl(sb, s.Length - 1, s);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    private void ReverseImpl(StringBuilder sb, int endIdx, string s)
    {
        if (startIdx < 0)
            return;
        sb.Append(s[endIdx]);
        ReverseImpl(sb, endIdx - 1, s);
    }
}
```

Тот же код, но рекурсия свёрнута в итерацию, тем самым решаются проблемы пп. 1 и 2:

```
static class StringHelper
{
    public string Reverse(string s)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (var endIdx = s.Length - 1; endIdx >= 0; endIdx--)
            sb.Append(s[endIdx]);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Теперь, можно вместо всей логики просто преобразовать вид данных, и воспользоваться быстрой библиотечной функцией:

```
static class StringHelper
{
    public string Reverse(string s)
    {
        var array = s.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(array);
        return new string(array);
    }
}
```

---

Тем не менее, последний вариант тоже не вполне точен, так как он не учитывает комбинирующиеся акценты Unicode. Jon Skeet написал про это (и многое другое) прекрасную статью: [OMG Ponies!!!](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail/) Для решения проблемы, мы должны переставлять не *символы*, а [*кластеры графем*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2f3k4f6.aspx):

```
static class StringHelper
{
    private IEnumerable<string> GetGraphemeClusters(string s)
    {
        var iter = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(s);
        while (iter.MoveNext())
            yield return iter.GetTextElement();
    }

    public string Reverse(string s)
    {
        var array = GetGraphemeClusters().ToArray();
        Array.Reverse(array);
        return string.Concat(array);
    }
}
```

Видите, насколько решение в книжке далеко от правильного?

Comment: Спасибо Вам за такой развернутый ответ.буду вникать

Comment: @Timothy: Пожалуйста! Последний пример сложный, и вы вполне имеете право его не полностью понять, остальные в принципе вполне доступны.

Comment: В начале Вашего поста мне не очень понятно На примере строки "ABCD":

начальный символ — 'A'
печатаем остаток "BCD" в обратном порядке, будет напечатано DCB
печатаем 'A', в итоге напечатано DCBA. как BCD печатается в обратном порядке

Comment: а потом к нему присоединяется A .

Comment: Ну, это рекурсия. Мы делим задачу на один символ и всё остальное.

Comment: а потом благодаря этой строчке в моем примере  Console.Write(str[0]); они выводятся  в обратном порядке?

Comment: @Timothy: Ну смотрите. Когда нам надо вывести строку, что это значит? Начальный символ должен вывестись последним, правильно? Вот это и делает код `Console.Write(str[0])`.

Comment: @Timothy: А код `DisplayRev(str.Substring(1, str.Length-1));` выводит хвост строки, потому что `str.Substring(1, str.Length-1)` — это и есть хвост.

Comment: спасибо еще раз. я понял

Comment: @Timothy: Пожалуйста!